# Finding a matrix-vector explicitly

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have an equation $A\begin{bmatrix}1&2&a\\0&3&b\\-1&4&c\\3&1&d\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}-2&5&6\\3&2&9\end{bmatrix}$ wherein from this, I know that the output of $A\begin{bmatrix}3a\\3b\\3c\\3d\end{bmatrix}$will defenitely be $\begin{bmatrix}6\\9\end{bmatrix}$ anyways due to the answer being given already. Yet how can I explicitly show that that is so explicitly, since the answer is pretty much obvious? I'm at loss on how to prove it.

Comment: No. If $A\pmatrix{a\\ b\\ c\\ d}=\pmatrix{6\\ 9}$, you should have $A\pmatrix{3a\\ 3b\\ 3c\\ 3d}=3\pmatrix{6\\ 9}=\pmatrix{18\\ 27}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true, notice that we have

$$A\begin{bmatrix}v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}Av_1 & Av_2 & Av_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

Hence we have

$$A\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 9\end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$$

Hence,

$$3A\begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \\ c \\ d \end{bmatrix}=3\begin{bmatrix} 6 \\ 9\end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$$

Comment: But wont $A$ shift to accommodate the $3$ scalar so that matrix(6,9) remains?

Comment: what do you mean by "shift"? Perhaps working with concrete example would help you? if $(1,2) = (1,2)$, if you multiply the left hand side by $3$, you would also multiply the right hand side by $3$ as well right?

Comment: Oh right! I was so dense. But would I go about proving that the equation is actually true, since I technically don't know $A$ and a,b,c,d are all real variables. I only know that the result is $\begin{bmatrix}18\\27\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: My equation $(1)$ would imply equation $(2)$. You do not need to know what are $A, a,b,c,d$ to know the quantity of your interest. It is like if you know $x+y=2$, even without having to know what are $x$ and $y$, you should be able to compute $2x+2y$.

Comment: Oh right, Thanks for helping me out!